# With Openssl, how to generate a certificate request from a public key?

Tags: cryptography, openssl, public-key-encryption

With Openssl, how could I create a certificate request, starting only from a public key ? (programmatically or not).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible with OpenSSL, because the CSR is always signed with the private key. But I found an online tool called [PKIWidgets](https://pkiwidgets.quovadisglobal.com/pkiwidgets/generateCSR.aspx) which is able to create a "stand-alone" CSR.

You might also find more information in the [CSR FAQ](http://www.redkestrel.co.uk/Articles/CSR.html#anchor-whats-in-a-csr).

Comment: @imichaelmiers: What are you talking about? *My* CSR is signed with *my* private key. If all I have is a public key I cannot create a valid CSR. Now, just because I sign it with my private key does not mean I need to reveal it to anyone, including the CA.

Comment: @GregS Apologies. I miss read your comment as regarding approving the csr, not generating it.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible, using openssl or any other software, to generate a CSR without the private key because a CSR must be signed with the corresponding private key.